# How to handle android gradle.properties file for different environments

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

im working with a version control system. 
in my windows client environment i've created a property in 'gradle.properties' 
i.e : myPath=c:/Program Files/aaa/bbbb

i've also a mac client environment,
how can i customize 'gradle.properties' to work with mac too.
i.e : myPath=/mac/aaa/bbbb

i dont want to edit the file manualy on mac each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a gradle.properties file in your **home directory**;

- on Windows: C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\gradle.properties
- on Mac: /Users/<username>/.gradle/gradle.properties

Create a new gradle.properties file in your home directory on each system, Windows and OSX, and add `myPath` property to those files.
Then remove that property(myPath) from your **project directory** gradle.properties, so that the property is no longer managed by your version control system.

Note that the gradle.properties file in **home directory** will be applied to all other gradle projects. I recommend you use a project specific property name, e.g. MY_PROJECT_A_PATH=/mac

Sources: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html